# Geolocation won't work in local project

Tags: html, laravel-5, geolocation

Is it possible to work with geolocation Api in laravel 5. I am on localhost with xampp and using php artisan serve to deploy my app using my computer. It won't detect my current geolocation.

Answer (score 0):

If are ran it on local machine without internet it will not work because for location it needs internet or please check that you have allowed from browser that browser can detect your location